# How can I get face normal after rotation?

Tags: javascript, three.js, normals

**Before I start, I realise this is a duplicate question.** However, there was no definitive answer for the other, just a work around that doesn't apply to me.

I am building a Rubik's cube using three.js. In order to create realistic rotations, I rotate them about a point. The function I am using is here:

```js
THREE.Object3D.prototype.rotateAroundWorldAxis = function () {

    // rotate object around axis in world space (the axis passes through point)
    // axis is assumed to be normalized
    // assumes object does not have a rotated parent

    var q = new THREE.Quaternion();

    return function rotateAroundWorldAxis(point, axis, angle) {

        q.setFromAxisAngle(axis, angle);

        this.applyQuaternion(q);

        this.position.sub(point);
        this.position.applyQuaternion(q);
        this.position.add(point);

        return this;

    }

}();
```

I also have built a manual function to calculate the face normals from 3 points. *I realise three.js has one of these, it is just my debugging process.* It operates just fine, but when I rotate a face on the Rubik's cube using a function, neither the normals built in or my function give the correct direction, they just return the direction they were originally facing. My function for normals is below.

```js
function computeNormal(p,face) {
    let a=p.geometry.vertices[face.a]
    let b=p.geometry.vertices[face.b]
    let c=p.geometry.vertices[face.c]
    let d=new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0)
    d.crossVectors(b.sub(a),c.sub(a))
    console.log(a,b,c,d)
    return d.normalize()
}
```

Any help is appreciated, and if you need any other pieces of my code I am happy to provide

Answer (score 0):

Typical of me to work it out after it's posted! I just realised we can get the rotation of the part containing the face and add its rotation to the faces (or something to that effect). The updated function:

```js
function computeNormal(p,face) {
    let n=face.normal
    let r=p.rotation
    n.applyEuler(r)
    console.log(n)
    return n
}
```

Comment: Please revise to show how you'd do that, then accept your answer if the post is resolved.